# How to create grid using ui component for custom eav model

Tags: magento2, admin, magento-2.1, grid, eav

I have created a new entity type and custom EAV model. Now i am trying to create grid for it using ui component. How we can use the eav data collection instead of flat table for grid?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Yes I did solve it by creating a new datasource which was pretty simple just extending Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider 
Let me know if you need any help with it. I will be really happy to help :)

Comment: Can you please upload your file code here? It will be really helpful for me and other also.

Comment: Hi @Sarvagya can you please upload your code in answer?

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. Hey Sorry for the late reply was away. I have mentioned the similar component file in the answer. I can't post the exact code due to some agreements. Let me know if you need any other help for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been able to do this within the admin section. You need to have your ResourceModel collection extend from the `\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection` class. Within your Grid Data provider, load the collection and use `addAttributeToSelect('*')`:

```
class Grid extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{    

public function __construct(
    ....
    \[Namespace]\[Module]\Model\ResourceModel\[Obj]\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $collection = $collectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $this->collection = $collection;
    ...
}}
```

which will load up the attribute values, then you need to specify the columns in the grid in your `[Namespace][Module]/view/[loc]/ui_component/[ui_component_grid_name].xml` layout:

```
<listing ...>
...
<columns ...>
    ...
    <column name="[attribute_code]">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                ...
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">[Attribute Label]</item>
                ...
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    ...
</columns>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is component file which can be helpful. This is not the exact code I am using but similar to that.

> P.S: I have used this code in 2017 for magento 2.1

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">vendorname_modulename_supplier_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Contact</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/edit</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendorname\Modulename\Ui\Component\Listing\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </bookmark>
        <component name="columns_controls">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.vendorname_modulename_supplier_columns</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </component>
        <filterSearch name="fulltext">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing_data_source</item>
                    <item name="chipsProvider" xsi:type="string">vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.listing_top.listing_filters_chips</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.search</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filterSearch>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.vendorname_modulename_supplier_columns</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.vendorname_modulename_supplier_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.vendorname_modulename_supplier_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/massDelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected items?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action name="edit">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Edit</item>
                        <item name="callback" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.vendorname_modulename_supplier_columns_editor</item>
                            <item name="target" xsi:type="string">editSelected</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.vendorname_modulename_supplier_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </container>
    <columns name="vendorname_modulename_supplier_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
                </item>
                <item name="editorConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.vendorname_modulename_supplier_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                    <item name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/inlineEdit"/>
                        <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.vendorname_modulename_supplier_columns_editor</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.vendorname_modulename_supplier_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root }</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="entity_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>       
        <column name="title">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Title</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="enabled" class="Vendorname\Modulename\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status" >
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Config\Source\Options\Yesno</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enabled</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="supplier_type" class="Vendorname\Modulename\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Contacttype">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Contact Type</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>        

        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Vendorname\Modulename\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ContactActions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```